# Content Provider no such table

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite

I am totally lost... here is my code:

```
public class MainContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
//DataBase
private WordsOpenHelper db_words;
private CategoryOpenHelper db_category;

//helper Strings to build the URI
private static String AUTHORITY = "com.ivanvoynov.dictionary.ContentProvider";
private static String BASE_PATH_WORDS = WordsOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME;
private static String BASE_PATH_CATEGORY = CategoryOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME;

//Content URI and the data types MIME
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_WORDS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH_WORDS);
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_CATEGORY = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH_CATEGORY);
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + BASE_PATH_WORDS;
public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + BASE_PATH_WORDS;

//our private variable to help match the URI types
private static final int ALL_ROWS_WORDS = 0;
private static final int ID_ROW_WORDS = 1;
private static final int ALL_ROWS_CATEGORY = 2;
private static final int ID_ROW_CATEGORY = 3;


//our URI matcher class to match our uri's
private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static{
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_WORDS, ALL_ROWS_WORDS);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_WORDS + "/#", ID_ROW_WORDS);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_CATEGORY, ALL_ROWS_CATEGORY);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_CATEGORY + "/#", ID_ROW_CATEGORY);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    db_words = new WordsOpenHelper(getContext());
    db_category = new CategoryOpenHelper(getContext());
    return false;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    //create the query builder
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();


    //our database initialization
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    Cursor cursor;

    //implement check column projection later on...

    //implement all of them to return all with specific crap.
    int uriType = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType){
        case ALL_ROWS_WORDS:
            //all words are asked
            database = db_words.getWritableDatabase();
            queryBuilder.setTables(WordsOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME);
            cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cursor;

        case ALL_ROWS_CATEGORY:
            //all words are asked
            database = db_category.getWritableDatabase();
            queryBuilder.setTables(db_category.TABLE_NAME);
            cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cursor;

        case ID_ROW_WORDS:
            //append to the table a new thing
            queryBuilder.setTables(db_words.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(db_words.KEY_ROW_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            database = db_words.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cursor;
        case ID_ROW_CATEGORY:
            //this is the category's row id selection
            queryBuilder.setTables(db_category.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(db_category.KEY_ROW_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            database = db_category.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cursor;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri + "URI TYPE = " + uriType);
    }
}
```

and this is the Open helper:

```
public class WordsOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //general info about the DataBase
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "vocabulary";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //DataBase columns
    public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_WORD = "word";
    public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = "definition";
    public static final String KEY_EXAMPLES = "examples";
    public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = "difficulty"; //new term
    public static final String KEY_SUBCATEGORY = "subcategory"; //new
    public static final String KEY_COLOR = "color"; //new
    public static final String KEY_LEARNED_FLAG = "learned_flag"; //new
    public static final String KEY_ARCHIVED_FLAG = "archived_flag"; //new
    public static final String KEY_TIMES_VIEWED = "times_viewed"; //count
    public static final String KEY_TIMES_CORRECT = "times_correct"; //new coint
    public static final String KEY_TIMES_INCORRECT = "times_incorrect"; //new
    public static final String KEY_TIMES_SKIPPED = "times_skipped"; //new
    public static final String KEY_LANGUAGE = "language"; //newone
    public static final String KEY_SYNONYMS = "synonyms";
    public static final String KEY_PART_OF_SPEECH = "part_of_speech";
    public static final String KEY_CATEGORIES = "categories";
    public static final String KEY_RECENT_FLAG = "recent_flag";
    public static final String KEY_UNDEFINED_FLAG = "defined_flag";

    //projection used in conjunction with other crap to form URI
    public static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            KEY_ROW_ID,
            KEY_WORD,
            KEY_DEFINITION,
            KEY_DIFFICULTY,
            KEY_EXAMPLES,
            KEY_SYNONYMS,
            KEY_PART_OF_SPEECH,
            KEY_CATEGORIES,
            KEY_RECENT_FLAG,
            KEY_UNDEFINED_FLAG,
            KEY_SUBCATEGORY,
            KEY_COLOR,
            KEY_LEARNED_FLAG,
            KEY_ARCHIVED_FLAG,
            KEY_TIMES_VIEWED,
            KEY_TIMES_CORRECT,
            KEY_TIMES_INCORRECT,
            KEY_TIMES_SKIPPED,
            KEY_LANGUAGE
    };

    //the table raw SQLite command to create it.
    private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + KEY_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_WORD + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_DEFINITION + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_DIFFICULTY + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY_EXAMPLES + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_SYNONYMS + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_PART_OF_SPEECH +" TEXT, "
                    + KEY_CATEGORIES + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_RECENT_FLAG + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_UNDEFINED_FLAG + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_SUBCATEGORY + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_COLOR + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_LEARNED_FLAG + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_ARCHIVED_FLAG + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_TIMES_VIEWED + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY_TIMES_CORRECT + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY_TIMES_INCORRECT + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY_TIMES_SKIPPED + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY_LANGUAGE + " TEXT "
                    + ");";


    public WordsOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVerson, int newVersion){
        //delete the table if it exists when upgrading
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

I keep on getting this error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: vocabulary (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, word, definition, difficulty, examples, synonyms, part_of_speech, categories, recent_flag, defined_flag, subcategory, color, learned_flag, archived_flag, times_viewed, times_correct, times_incorrect, times_skipped, language FROM vocabulary
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
        at com.ivanvoynov.dictionary.ContentProvider.MainContentProvider.query(MainContentProvider.java:80)
```

I have wasted the whole night... It as i understand says that the table has not been created. Why it has not been created i do not understand. When I reinstalled the app this is what i keep on getting.

Comment: **Uninstall** your app so the old version of the database is removed and `onCreate()` is run again.

Comment: It doesn't help, it always gets stuck on queryBuilder.query() function. It seems like the open helper didn't create the table before it is accessed by the content provider...

Comment: What's the other database helper and is it by any chance using the same database file?

Comment: run sqlite3 with your db as an parameter and type .schema

Comment: @laalto YES! INDEED! Thank you, I was silly enough to copy the database helper and have two of them. Essentially when the second one was created (both using the same DATABASE name) it removed the previous one with it's tables. SOLUTION: MERGE TWO DATABASE OPEN HELPERS INTO ONE. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, you have two database helper that are using the same database file. Here's what happens:

1. Helper 1 database is created on first call to `getWritableDatabase()`. The helper's `onCreate()` is invoked. The database file's version is set to `DATABASE_VERSION`.
2. Helper 2's database is opened on a call to its `getWritableDatabase()`. The database file already exists and is of the correct version, so no `onUpgrade()` or `onCreate()` is invoked. But this database doesn't have helper 2's tables.

Solution: Only one database helper per database file. You can have multiple tables in one helper.